# Alternate color based on nth-child(n) selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a `div` with alternate class name with 1 parent.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

I want to color all `.head` with alternate gray and dark gray.

Is there's a problem with my CSS?

```
.parent .head:nth-child(2n) {
   background-color: gray;
}
.parent .head {
   background-color: dark-gray;
}
```

I also used `odd` for this

```
.parent .head:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: gray;
}
```

But it also counts the `.body` class.

Comment: Do you have a fixed pattern that a `.head` will always be followed by a `.body`?

Comment: yes Sir .. Im trying this solution. a combination of odd with n 
.parent > .head:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: gray;
}
.parent > .head:nth-child(3n + 2) {
 background-color: dark-gray;
}

but it still not working for alternation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, let me explain why the selectors that you have tried so far doesn't work. `*-child` selectors work only based on the element and not the extra conditions that are attached to it. So, in your case, the `.head` elements are the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th children under their parent.

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="head"></div> <!-- this is always the 1st child of its parent -->
  <div class="body"></div> <!-- this is always the 2nd child of its parent -->
  <div class="head"></div> <!-- this is always the 3rd child of its parent -->
  <div class="body"></div> <!-- this is always the 4th child of its parent -->
  <div class="head"></div> <!-- this is always the 5th child of its parent -->
  <div class="body"></div> <!-- this is always the 6th child of its parent -->
  <div class="head"></div> <!-- this is always the 7th child of its parent -->
  <div class="body"></div> <!-- this is always the 8th child of its parent -->
</div>
```

That would mean that the below selector would not select any element because `2n` selects 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th elements but those elements do not have `class='head'`.

```css
.parent .head:nth-child(2n) {
   background-color: gray;
}
```

The below selector would select 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th elements and so on. They all have `class='head'` but the problem is that all the `.head` elements are odd numbered children of their parent and so this would apply the style to all `.head` elements and not produce an alternating color effect.

```css
.parent .head:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: gray;
}
```

---

Given that your elements have a fixed pattern, you can use `4n+1` and `4n+3`  as parameters for the nth child selector and style the elements.

The logic for identifying the `an+b` pattern is very simple. In your structure, the 1st, 5th, 9th... elements need to have one color whereas the 3rd, 7th, 11th... elements need to have another color. As we can see, the difference between each number is 4 and so the multiplication factor is `4`. The first series of elements differ from `4n` series by 1 and so the pattern to select them is `4n+1` while the other series of elements differ from `4n` series by 3 and so their pattern is `4n+3`.

```css
.parent .head:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background-color: gray;
}
.parent .head:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="head">A</div>
  <div class="body">A</div>
  <div class="head">A</div>
  <div class="body">A</div>
  <div class="head">A</div>
  <div class="body">A</div>
  <div class="head">A</div>
  <div class="body">A</div>
</div>
```